# Kafka consumer pauses message cosumption for some partitions and they are not resumed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have an issue with our KafkaStreams. We can see log messages to show that some partitions are 'paused'. But could not find the root cause.
The debug logs below show that a FetchRequest is sent but no FetchResponse. The consumer is paused few milliseconds after the FetchRequest is sent. It is not resumed after this.

Could there be any reason for this? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
09:42:16.223 [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=iona-service] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition engagement-7 at position FetchPosition{offset=340025464, offsetEpoch=Optional[55], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[XXX.XXX.X.XXX:13598 (id: 47 rack: null)], epoch=55}} to node XXX.XXX.X.XXX:13598 (id: 47 rack: null)

09:42:16.223 [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=iona-service] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(engagement-7), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker XXX.XXX.X.XXX:13598 (id: 47 rack: null)

09:42:16.224 [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=iona-service] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=13, clientId=iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1-consumer, correlationId=354) and timeout 30000 to node 47: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=1933849832, sessionEpoch=266, topics=[FetchTopic(topic='engagement', topicId=lOuiz7L8RuarZCiPp2fpBg, partitions=[FetchPartition(partition=7, currentLeaderEpoch=55, fetchOffset=340025464, lastFetchedEpoch=-1, logStartOffset=-1, partitionMaxBytes=1048576)])], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')

//This log message might be the result of some other fetch I think
09:42:16.224 [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] Main Consumer poll completed in 9 ms and fetched 1 records

09:42:16.225 [iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=iona-service-ae06467b-d598-4cba-9e62-22f3e3975bb6-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=iona-service] Pausing partitions [engagement-7]
```

Comment: Kafka Streams may `pause()` partitions during processed for different reasons. Without more logging information, it's not possible to know why pausing happens, and/or why those partitions might not be resumed (they should be resumed at some point).